# From an included JSP, how do we access a variable declared in another included JSP (same parent)

Tags: jsp, jspinclude

I have a parent JSP with code that looks like

```
<jsp:include page='a.jsp' flush='true'/>
<jsp:include page='b.jsp' flush='true'/>
<jsp:include page='c.jsp' flush='true'/>
```

`a.jsp` has a Java object which I need to access in `c.jsp`

Is there a way to do this without moving any code from a.jsp to the parent jsp?

Here is how the a.jsp looks like:

```
<%@ page import="com.xxx.yyy.myClass" %>
<%
    // Some processing here
%>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="scrollableTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <%
            // Some processing here
            w_myObject = myAPI.getmyObject(param1, param2);
            // Some processing here
        %>
        </tr>
        <!-- Display contents of w_myObject in subsequent rows of this table, here -->
    </thead>
</table>
```

And I want to access w_myObject in c.jsp

Comment: I edited the question with some code from a.jsp. Have a look. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all to do with scopes.  If your Object is in Request scope then of course it will have access.  Or if it is in Session scope it will have access.  However, if it is in PageContext scope I believe it will be lost, as each jsp include creates its own scope.

So what I'm trying to say is put the Object in request scope and it will be visible across all JSPs.

```
**a.jsp**
request.setAttribute("myObjectKey", w_myObject);

**c.jsp**
w_myObject = (TypeOfMyObject)request.getAttribute("myObjectKey");
```

Comment: erm... can you tell me how to do that? please see the code in the question. thanks!

Comment: Well scriptlets aren't nice, so you'd probably want to look at setting the Object in request scope in your servlet (not JSP) and then access it through JSTL or something.  However in your a.jsp you want to do request.setAttribute("myObjectKey", w_myObject); and in c.jsp you want to do w_myObject = request.getAttribute("myObjectKey");  You will need to cast.

Comment: Thank you @planetjones. Putting the Object in request scope as you've shown in your sample code worked for me :)